# Find maximum of the function $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}-1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Let $x\ge0$. Find maximum
$$f(x)=\dfrac{e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}-1}{x}$$

I think this maximum is $2$, I hope this problem have some nice solution,Thank you

Comment: What have you done? Why do you think that the answer is 2?

Comment: because I find this $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=2$,if  we have prove $f'(x)<0,x\ge 0$, that $f(x)\le 2$,this problem maybe have  other nice methods

Comment: No maximum found when $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f=\dfrac{e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}-1}{x}$$
$$f'=\dfrac{{\Bigg(\frac{2x}{(1+x)^2}\cdot e^\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)}\Bigg)-\Big(e^\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right) -1\Big)}{x^2}$$
$$f'=-\dfrac{(1+x^2)\cdot e^\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right) -(1+x)^2}{x^2(1+x)^2}$$
$$f'=\dfrac{-(1+x^2)\bigg(e^\frac{2x}{1+x}-1\bigg)+2x}{x^2(1+x)^2}\le0 \forall x\ge0$$

So, $f$ decreases for all $x\ge0$ [because $f'\le0$, see this plot of $f'$ numerator](http://goo.gl/Ntm3h).

and $$\lim_{x\to 0}f=2;\  \text{ :use L-Hospitals' Rule}$$

And at $x=-1$ function goes undefined and $f=-\infty$
And after which graph is as shown.

It rises till x=0 and then again steeps down.
[image]

Comment: Thank you,@exploringnet,but f' you have some wrong.

Comment: @exploringnet,why $f'\le 0$,have nice solve?

Comment: mean:why $e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}\ge\dfrac{(1+x)^2}{x^2+1}$?have nice solve? I think we can use ugly methods:$g(x)=(x^2+1)e^{\frac{2x}{x+1}}-(x+1)^2$, then we have $g'(x)=$ , http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/i=%28x%5E2%2B1%29e%5E%28%282x%29%2F%28x%2B1%29%29-%28x%2B1%29%5E2

Comment: Oh,Thank you,That's nice solution!